# CSS: Page 'Jumps' when visited or reloaded

Tags: css

I built a site in Drupal 8 (but I think this is a CSS question).

The page 'jumps' when you reload the page. It also does this when you first visit but you can see it better if you hit 'f5'. I tried removing the logo to see if that was causing the problem, but it wasn't...the page still 'jumps'.

It looks like the big, rust-colored navigation bar at the top moves to the left when it reloads and then re-positions itself to where it's 'supposed' to be.

Anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Its the image on the navbar - `<img src="/themes/custom/grantstation/images/GrantStation-Logo.png" alt="Home" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: Cache static resources like images, CSS, JS etc. so users don't have to download them again and again when they switch pages or come back to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [Flash of Unstyled Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). It happens when the text is shown on the screen before its fonts are loaded. When the fonts finish loading, the text jumps into a new position.

See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/) for a number different techniques to combat it!